# Unique names as primary keys in JHipster tables?

Tags: jhipster

I am evaluating `JHipster` and I am wondering why unique fields 
`(login in T_USER and name in T_AUTHORITY)` are primary keys instead of auto-generated numbers (IDs) as it is the case in `T_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT`?

Thanks,
Milan

Answer (score 0):

I think it's using the old fashioned kind of primary key, so we must choose the primary key value first rather than sequence number as id, there is pros of using the value such as ROLE_ADMIN, or ROLE_USER rather than integer 1 or 2 as primary key